# How to restart a PM2 process if no new logs for the last X minutes?

Tags: pm2

I'm looking to restart a PM2 process if no new logs for the last X minutes, but not sure if that's possible

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure which kinds of logs you are looking for, but I assume you want PM2 to restart the application from the start every so many minutes even if there were no unhandled errors.

If this is the case for your issue, you can create a simple setTimeout that will kill your process X minutes after it was started, which will then cause PM2 to restart it from scratch.

This piece of code should suffice:

```
setTimeout(() => {
    process.exit(0);
}, X * 60000);
```

Just make sure to replace "X" with the number of minutes you need to wait before restarting the application. The number "60000" is 60 (seconds) * 1000 (milliseconds) since setTimeout expects an integer value in milliseconds.